# Swift - execute Javascript on each page

Tags: javascript, html, ios, swift, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView to which I pass a HTML file to load.

The HTML file includes javascript that looks for the existence of a variable.
If it exists, it performs one action, if the variable doesn't exist, the script performs another action.

```
if(typeof customVar === 'undefined')
  //Perform task1
else
  // Perform task 2 using customVar
```

On the native, I use the function stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString to set the variable before the page is loaded.
To do so, I'm setting the code in webViewDidStartLoad (I also tried to place it in shouldStartLoadWithRequest).

```
func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView)
{
    let cutVar = "test"
    webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("customVar = '\(cutVar)';")
}
```

This works well when I load a page for the first time, but only the first time.
After that, it seems that through the webViewDidStartLoad, we re-assign the variable in the current page, and then reload the page itself.
So that means, the page is reloaded without the variable to be set.

Is there a way to say I want to run the javascript bit for the next page to load?
Maybe something like a global variable always accessible?

Thank you.

Comment: shouldStartLoadWithRequest will be invoked for every request the webview tries to load.. If you tried it and if it still didn't work, i'd verify the html/JS to see what is going on

Comment: The javascript is basically what's I've put in the description. It starts with checking the existence of the variable and form the second load, it says it is not there ...